# VirtualBox Fullscreen Host OS Toolbar still visible

Tags: virtualbox

Im trying very hard to like virtualbox, but so far I find it so much worse than vmplayer in so many ways. If it wouldnt take me hours to install everything back into vmplayer i would have moved back days ago

When I open my ubuntu vm my host OS's (windows 10) toolbar is still visible at the bottom of the screen, cutting off the actual virtualbox toolbar

Please help me

(edit) It is in fullscreen mode already, it just still shows the toolbar/taskbar from the host OS

Answer (score 26):

Open Task Manager of Windows 10, Select "Windows Explorer" and Restart.
[Reference Link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6RyggFOLiI&vl=en)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same issue. The Windows 10 taskbar was still showing when I had VirtualBox in fullscreen mode, and what caused it for me was I had a program called Rufus *(for creating bootable USBs)* open and it was keeping the taskbar from hiding. Once I closed Rufus, everything worked as it should. So, maybe you had a program keeping focus on the taskbar, something that needed attention, and wouldn't let the taskbar hide.

Comment: For me it was GitKraken causing the host Windows taskbar to keep showing.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the problem once. Not sure what had caused the that but I managed to find a solution by enabling "task bar" hiding option in host windows 10 machine.

Right Click on Task Bar -> Task Bar Setting -> Enable Task Bar hiding Option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are able to switch to fullscreen mode on the VM, this should hide the Host OS.

This image shows you where you can find the option:
[image: Virtualbox - fix full screen problem for all OS]

If this is not what you are looking for, please elaborate on your problem, maybe add a screenshot showing the problem you are having.

Comment: I was obviously super frustrated when i wrote that question, but its still pretty much it. A screenshot isnt really going to show any more info: It is in fullscreen mode already, it just still shows the toolbar/taskbar from the host OS. So everything looks perfectly fine like fullscreen mode, except windows's toolbar still at the bottom of the screen

Comment: Although this is not the solution, it saved me when you said `screenshot`. Just pressed `PrtSc` and left fullscreen

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced this exact problem, namely Windows 10 host taskbar would not go away despite the guest being in full screen. Even though this question is old, since this question got the top google page rank, I thought I would share how I fixed it.

I fixed it by shutting down Virtualbox and then rebooting the Windows 10 host. It is possible as others have pointed out that some app was keeping the taskbar active, but I couldn't find any such app. If it was some rogue app that was just running as a process (with no taskbar presence), the reboot nuked it from orbit and fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

After installation virtualbox tools You can press 
host + F (in my case Ctrl + F) 
buttons to run fullscreen in virtualbox.

Comment: Thanks but it is in fullscreen mode already, it just still shows the toolbar/taskbar from the host OS

Comment: Can You give some screen with this problem?